# Azure CosmosDb DocumentQuery returns HasMoreResults as true but ExecuteNextASync returns 0 count

Tags: xamarin, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to retrieve results from Azure CosmosDb. Below code returns HasMoreResults equal to true; however when I call ExecuteNextASync; I don't get any result. I have read through a few similar issues but could not yet identify a definitive solution. Thanks for the help!

```
public async Task<List<Trackers>> GetTrackersDataAsync()
    {
        try
        {

            var query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Trackers>(collectionLink, new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = -1, EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true })
                              .OrderByDescending(x => x.LocatedAt)
                               .AsDocumentQuery();           


            MFZTrackers = new List<Trackers>();

            while (query.HasMoreResults)
            {

                var result = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<Trackers>();
                MFZTrackers.AddRange(result);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(@"ERROR {0}", e.Message);
            return null;
        }

        return MFZTrackers;
    }
```

Comment: does result.ContinuationToken has any value after 1st execution ?

Comment: Resolved. Above was functioning properly, problem was at the class calling the method.